# How can Perl's Template remove the whitespace following a directive?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have the following template

```
[% DEFAULT label = 'null' %]
order: '[% order %]',
name:  '[% name %]',
product:'[% product %]',
label : '[% label %]'
```

which included on a template my.tt file

on Perl I have the following configuration :

```
my $template    = Template->new();
open(my $fh, '>:raw', \$report); 
$template->process('my.tt', \%data,$fh) or die $template->error();
print $report;
```

when i print $report i see on the first line -> new line then the info like below printed, how can i remove the new line char from the first line?

```
order: 'order1'
name: 'testname'
product: 'testproduct'
label: 'label1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Simply use `-%]` instead of `%]`.](https://metacpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/view/lib/Template/Manual/Syntax.pod#Chomping-Whitespace)